# Javascript: Dynamic variable name with `this`?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to factorize a method, will be passing in certain keywords into it, example `keywordA`, `keywordB`, and I want to perform certain actions with these keywords using jquery and Tether javascript library.

```
let wrapperTetherName = `${containerName}WrapperTether`;
```

This is ok and returns the right name example keywordAWrapperTether, keywordBWrapperTether

---

How do I do something like (obviously incorrect syntax) :

```
if (!this.`${wrapperTetherName}`) // this.wrapperTetherName returns undefined
```

Or any ideas for alternatives? I just want to check the existence of `this.keywordAWrapperTetherName`, if it doesn't exist then create a new instance of Tether for it, otherwise, destroy it.

Comment: `this[wrapperTetherName]`

Comment: Thanks! @Ry- , worked well, didnt think of it at first but it makes sense given `this` is an object